# How to write n_10 in math-mode

Tags: math-mode

I'm writing some notes about numerical analise and I want to write a line as fallows:

351_10 = 101100000_2 = 540_8 = 160_16

This is the notation to describe when numbers are written in different bases as in 111_2 would mean the binary number 111 that is represent in base ten as 7_10.

[image]

mathpix is supposed to convert the raw: 351_2 into the same number but with the 2 being subscript. It works with single digit numbers as in 351_2 will show correctly with the 2 sub-scripted. But it does not work with double digit numbers, as in 351_79 will show 7 sub-scripted but not the 9.

[image]

I tried using several combinations of brackets and also tried to read the mathpix wiki syntax but I could not find the solution. I suspect it may have something to do with the aligh keyword.

This was the mathpix guide I used: https://mathpix.com/docs/mathpix-markdown/syntax-reference#align%2C-split%2C-gather-equation-environments

- OS: Linux
- text editor: Mark Text

Comment: In LaTeX you should always use curly braces for sub- and superscripts: `160_{16}`.

Comment: curly braces fixed it. Sorry I though this engine was called mathpix so I went into the wrong syntax guide. I think mathpix is some sorth of implementation of math-mode for javascript. Write an answare and I will award you, thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In (La)TeX you want to use curly braces around sub- and superscripts that consist of several characters (tokens). I'm assuming this is going to be similar for the various tools out there that accept TeX-like input, but are not really TeX.

I recommend you always add the braces even if your sub- or superscript consists of only a single character (token).

```
351_{10} = 101100000_{2} = 540_{8} = 160_{16}
```